# Is there anyway to speed up signal processing in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I'm doing some radio signal processing with SP toolbox in MATLAB. Because of the high number of virtual radio antennas that I'm working on, I want to know if there is anyway to make the process faster.

Here is what I do normally:

1. Inserting some excel like data with 3 column (actually 4 but one of them is time that I use it in another way) into MATLAB ( x,y,z of radio antenna positions ), which I name them respectively like x75, y75,z75 for an antenna positioned at 75 meter from the core.

   [image]
2. Convert them to another unit which is straight forward because I use the command line

   [image]
3. Then I use the SP toolbox to insert the converted values as a signal which is time-consuming because I need to insert a lot of them one by one!

   [image]
4. Then I should apply a bandpass filter with FFT algorithm to those signals again one by one...

   [image]
5. Then I need to export those filtered signals into workspace and save the peak of the FFT transformed signals ( Y stats ) for later use ( I do use the `plot` command ):

   ```
   plot(abs(fft(x75f.data)))
   ```

   [image]

*now think of it if I'm doing this for 100 radio antennas with x,y and z coordinates ... is there anyway to do any of those parts in command line? Like applying filter on converted values without having to do it in SP toolbox? *
Any way to do it faster?*

filter specification:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, and the GUI usually tells you how.  For example, you've selected to use the FFT-accelerated filtering function `fftfilt`.  So the command-line version is

```
x75f = fftfilt(filt1, x75);
```

The statistics you can calculate with e.g. `min`, `max` functions.

Are you actually using the filtered time signal, or just using its FFT?  If all you need is the FFT, it is a waste to have fftfilt do an inverse FFT and then you FFT it again.  Just take the FFT of the original, and use multiplication in the frequency domain to apply your filter.

Comment: Thanks!...great reply , i'm just using FFT but don't know how I can use multiplication in the frequency domain to apply my filter yet!....may you also tell me how I can save the peak value with max function in command-line, please?

Comment: @MohammadSobbouhi: Do you know $H(j \omega)$ for your filter?

Comment: For the other part, just `spec = abs(fft(x75f.data)); max(spec)`

Comment: the filter specification is like the last image that I've added to the question...i'm not sure if i'm doing that right or wrong but all I want is to filter those signals in 32-64 MHZ band and find the peak of the frequency-domain value.

Comment: and about finding max, your command works but it seems to write the max to the same ans value for all singals...anyway to write the max to different value for each signal ?....I just need the y stats max.

Comment: @MohammadSobbouhi: You can surely do `x75insertionloss = max(spec);` to save it into a variable.

Comment: oh, great! thank you...may you please take a look at the filter specification and tell me if i'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: Not wrong per se, but slower than necessary.  Are you actually just looking for the maximum frequency component in your passband?  You could take the FFT, do no filtering at all, but call `max` passing only a slice of the FFT.

Comment: i'm looking for the maximum frequency component in 32-64 MHZ not in all frequency spectrum so I think I have to use filtering.

Comment: @MohammadSobbouhi: No, it should be faster to do `spec = fft(x75); x75insertionloss = max(spec(i_32mhz:i_64mhz));`  Of course the correct indexes depend on the length of your `x75` vector, since that determines the frequency resolution of the FFT.

Comment: yes, you're right...the length is 2082.thanks a lot for your help....it saved me a lot of time!